# Using a List in PlotLabel which goes beyond width of ImageSize

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling

My `PlotLabel` goes beyond the width of the `ImageSize`. The label is generated into a `List` form by my program. I hope to allow my `PlotLabel` to go to a second, third, fourth (...) line if it reaches beyond the boundaries. My problem in simplified, working code:

```
testList = {1.1`, 1.2100000000000002`, 1.4641000000000004`, 
   2.143588810000001`, 4.594972986357221`, 21.1137767453526`, 
   445.7915684525922`, 198730.12250342217`, 3.949366159022518`*^10, 
   1.5597493058032278`*^21, 2.432817896953651`*^42, 
   5.918602919737985`*^84, 3.5029860521531003`*^169, 
   1.22709112815791634686748164742131068419446205954341`15.\
653559774527023*^339, 
   1.50575263680386788043945221511499961813146`15.352529778863042*^\
678, 2.2672910032418008565810795918131168775255956636`15.\
051499783199061*^1356, 
   5.1406084933812118223464178513329285`14.75046978753508*^2712, 
   2.64258556822230525123173280428744040060801405497404`14.\
449439791871098*^5425, 
   6.98325848537680392124060228920952089211156`14.148409796207117*^\
10850, 4.8765899073587133585511396520327915438254972718`13.\
847379800543136*^21701};
Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, 
 PlotLabel -> StringForm["The orbit of x=1.1 is\n``\n", testList ], 
 ImageSize -> {600, 600}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you create a `TextCell` then it will wrap the list nicely. `PageWidth` controls the width of the text cell.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, PlotLabel -> 
    StringForm["The orbit of x=1.1 is\n``\n", TextCell[testList, PageWidth -> 600]],  
    ImageSize -> {600, 600}]
```

[image]

You can change the appearance of the TextCell (font, fontsize, color, etc) using various options as shown in the help files for `TextCell` and `Cell`.

Comment: The copied code sends my list to two lines instead of one, but still goes beyond the viewable area.

Comment: Above is the picture I got. You know.. if you play with the window width it changes the layout of the textcell. Maybe my default window width is different from yours...

Comment: Could I change the width of the `TextCell`? Its for a .cdf file and the output size needs to be constrained somewhat.

Comment: See the change -- this one gives me the same picture, but now the width of the textcell is specified (and it doesn't change when you resize the window).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank-you very much!

Answer (score 7):

Slightly better than my last attempt:

```
Row[{
  Plot[x^2, {x, -3, 3}, ImageSize -> {400, 400}],
  Panel[testList, "The orbit of x=1.1 is", Top, 
   ImageSize -> {400, 120}]
  }]
```

[image: panel]

Comment: Nice solution!!

Answer (score 4):

A nine-character solution: add `~Pane~600` to the end of the `PlotLabel`.